# How to inject (a lot of) code into a running program?

Tags: windows, injection

I've seen a number of tutorials on changing several binary digits of an executable, like changing assembly `je` to `jn`. But what I want to add new functionalities.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
//#include <algorithm>

struct StateData {
    std::string state;
    std::string governor;
    int population;
};

//bool sortByPopulation(const StateData& s1, const StateData& s2) {
//    return s1.population > s2.population;
//}

int main() {
    std::string filepath;
    std::cout << "Enter the path to the CSV file: ";
    std::cin >> filepath;

    std::ifstream file(filepath);

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open file " << filepath << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Skip the header line
    std::string line;
    std::getline(file, line);

    std::vector<StateData> data;

    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::string state, governor;
        int population;
        std::getline(ss, state, ',');
        std::getline(ss, governor, ',');
        ss >> population;
        data.push_back({state, governor, population});
    }

//    std::sort(data.begin(),data.end(), sortByPopulation);


    const int stateWidth = 15;
    const int governorWidth = 20;
    const int populationWidth = 10;

    std::cout << std::left
              << "| " << std::setw(stateWidth) << "State"
              << "| " << std::setw(governorWidth) << "Governor"
              << "| " << std::setw(populationWidth) << "Population"
              << "|\n";

    std::cout << "| " << std::setfill('-')
              << std::setw(stateWidth) << ""
              << "| " << std::setw(governorWidth) << ""
              << "| " << std::setw(populationWidth) << ""
              << std::setfill(' ') << "|\n";

    for (const auto &d: data) {
        std::cout << std::left
                  << "| " << std::setw(stateWidth) << d.state
                  << "| " << std::setw(governorWidth) << d.governor
                  << "| " << std::setw(populationWidth) << d.population
                  << "|\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my sample crackme in C++. It reads a CSV file and each line is parsed into a State object, and print them.

Unfortunately, the crackme didn't come with a sorting. I want to inject a sorting logic into the running crackme. For now, I need the program to output states with respect to population size.

I figure patching, creating a new binary file, is hard because all other addresses will change.

I analyzed the executable with IDA Disassembler. I guess I've found the place that the program starts to loop the list.

What's the next step? I don't know if it's DLL injection or what kind of injection.

[image]

Comment: It is DLL injection.